# Storyboard does not change when I change style in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-style, wpf-animation

I want to run a simple animation on an arrow picture (png). The arrow points either downwards or upwards, and the animation is supposed to be a wave going through the arrow in the direction it points at.

I use the Image control and assign one of two styles to it. These styles define the picture to use and three double animations in a storyboard. The animation is supposed to run unconditionally, just from the moment the Image is created, forever. One of the styles is an arrow pointing upwards with a wave moving upwards (*Trend_Rising*), and the other style is an arrow pointing downwards with wave going downwards (*Trend_Falling*).

The following is the Image, and the style is in a separate file referenced from the UserControl where the Image is embedded.

```
<Image x:Name="TrendImg" Style="{DynamicResource Trend_Falling}" />
```

This is the content of the styles file:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

     <Style x:Key="Trend_Base" TargetType="Image">

        <Setter Property="OpacityMask">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,1" EndPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" />
                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" />
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="Trend_Rising_Base" TargetType="Image" BasedOn="{StaticResource Trend_Base}">

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsVisible" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="OpacityMask.GradientStops[0].Offset" From="-0.1" To="0.9" Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="OpacityMask.GradientStops[1].Offset" From="0.0"  To="1.0" Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="OpacityMask.GradientStops[2].Offset" From="0.1"  To="1.1" Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="Trend_Falling_Base" TargetType="Image" BasedOn="{StaticResource Trend_Base}">

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsVisible" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="OpacityMask.GradientStops[0].Offset" From="0.9" To="-0.1" Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="OpacityMask.GradientStops[1].Offset" From="1.0" To="0.0"  Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="OpacityMask.GradientStops[2].Offset" From="1.1" To="0.1"  Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="Trend_Rising" TargetType="Image" BasedOn="{StaticResource Trend_Rising_Base}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="trend_rising.png" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="Trend_Falling" TargetType="Image" BasedOn="{StaticResource Trend_Falling_Base}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="trend_falling.png" />
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

The thing is that when I change the style programmatically, the animation does not change. For instance, if I start the application (the Image has the *Trend_Falling* style assigned), the downward arrow will be displayed with wave animation moving downwards as it should. But when I change the style to *Trend_Rising* at runtime, the arrow picture changes as it should, but the animation remains the same.

```
TrendImg.SetResourceReference(Control.StyleProperty, "Trend_Rising")
```

What am I doing wrong? I will be grateful for any help. Thank you!

**-- EDIT --**

I created an *ImageWithAnim* class which is a descendant of *Image*, and added a boolean *Animate* dependency property to it. Then I attached the trigger to that property instead of *IsVisible*. True starts the storyboard and false is supposed to stop it, but it does not... When I set *Animate* to false, an exception is thrown saying that the name *RisingStoryboard* can not be resolved in the namespace *System.Windows.Style*. I found several posts on StackOverflow according to which this example should work (among those that claimed it won't :-) ).

So... now I have no idea how to do it right. I will be grateful for any help. Thank you!

This is the changed xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Test="clr-namespace:StyleChangeTest">

    <Style x:Key="Trend_Base" TargetType="Test:ImageWithAnim">

        <Setter Property="OpacityMask">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,1" EndPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" />
                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" />
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="Trend_Rising_Base" TargetType="Test:ImageWithAnim" BasedOn="{StaticResource Trend_Base}">

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Animate" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="RisingStoryboard">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="OpacityMask.GradientStops[0].Offset" From="-0.1" To="0.9" Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="OpacityMask.GradientStops[1].Offset" From="0.0"  To="1.0" Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="OpacityMask.GradientStops[2].Offset" From="0.1"  To="1.1" Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>

            <Trigger Property="Animate" Value="False">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="RisingStoryboard" />
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="Trend_Falling_Base" TargetType="Test:ImageWithAnim" BasedOn="{StaticResource Trend_Base}">

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Animate" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="FallingStoryboard">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="OpacityMask.GradientStops[0].Offset" From="0.9" To="-0.1" Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="OpacityMask.GradientStops[1].Offset" From="1.0" To="0.0"  Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="OpacityMask.GradientStops[2].Offset" From="1.1" To="0.1"  Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>

            <Trigger Property="Animate" Value="False">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FallingStoryboard" />
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>                
        </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="Trend_Rising" TargetType="Test:ImageWithAnim" BasedOn="{StaticResource Trend_Rising_Base}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="trend_rising.png" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="Trend_Falling" TargetType="Test:ImageWithAnim" BasedOn="{StaticResource Trend_Falling_Base}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="trend_falling.png" />
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

And here's the *ImageWithAnim* class:

```
Public Class ImageWithAnim
    Inherits Image

    Private Shared _animate As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Animate",
                                                                                GetType(Boolean),
                                                                                GetType(ImageWithAnim),
                                                                                New PropertyMetadata(defaultValue:=False))

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property AnimateProperty As DependencyProperty
        Get
            Return _animate
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property Animate() As Boolean
        Get
            Return CBool(GetValue(_animate))
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            SetValue(_animate, value)
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: You're Targeting just an Image TargetType. So it doesn't care that the image itself has changed, just that there's an image. If you're going to go this route then when you change the Image source, you'll need to manually stop/start swap between the separate animations.

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisW., but what way would you stop the animation and restart it? I know WPF to some extent, but I'm not a specialist. Can it be done in a simple way using a style, or should it be done programmatically? The first idea that comes to my mind is create an Image class descendant with a property that determines whether the animation should start or stop. Then use that class instead of Image and attach the trigger to that property instead of IsVisible. Is it a good idea or can it all be done simpler?

Comment: I created a descendant of Image with a boolean Animate dependency property. I used it in style instead of IsVisible and I managed to start the animation by setting Animate to True. However, stopping it by setting Animate to False didn't work. So I added a second trigger attached to Animate=False with a StopStoryboard element that had BeginStoryBoardName set to the x:Name of the BeginStoryboard defined for Animate=True. Now every time I set Animate to False, I get an exception saying that the specified BeginStoryboard name can not be resolved in the System.Windows.Style namespace. I'm stuck.

Comment: Ok I will try to swing back to this when I find some free time. Have a lot more going on this week than normal.

Comment: It's fine, I don't want to bother you too much. I appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: No worries man, everybody needs help sometime, we've all been there. I will try to find time today. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By coincidence I have just found an answer to my own question. The names of the storyboards could not be resolved because they were defined in base styles. When I defined them directly in my two styles of interest, I could start and stop them using the *Animate* property of *ImageWithAnim* as expected, without any exceptions.

So, when changing the style of the image, I have to do the following:

```
TrendImg.Animate = False
TrendImg.SetResourceReference(ImageWithAnim.StyleProperty, "Trend_Falling")
TrendImg.Animate = True
```

Now the animation is changed properly, and the wave animation moves in the direction the arrow points to, which is what I wanted to achieve.

And here's the changed style:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Test="clr-namespace:StyleChangeTest">

    <Style x:Key="Trend_Base" TargetType="Test:ImageWithAnim">

        <Setter Property="OpacityMask">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,1" EndPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" />
                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" />
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="Trend_Rising" TargetType="Test:ImageWithAnim" BasedOn="{StaticResource Trend_Base}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="trend_rising.png" />

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Animate" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="RisingStoryboard">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="OpacityMask.GradientStops[0].Offset" From="-0.1" To="0.9" Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="OpacityMask.GradientStops[1].Offset" From="0.0"  To="1.0" Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="OpacityMask.GradientStops[2].Offset" From="0.1"  To="1.1" Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>

                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="RisingStoryboard" />
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="Trend_Falling" TargetType="Test:ImageWithAnim" BasedOn="{StaticResource Trend_Base}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="trend_falling.png" />

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Animate" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="FallingStoryboard">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="OpacityMask.GradientStops[0].Offset" From="0.9" To="-0.1" Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="OpacityMask.GradientStops[1].Offset" From="1.0" To="0.0"  Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="OpacityMask.GradientStops[2].Offset" From="1.1" To="0.1"  Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>

                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FallingStoryboard" />
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

And to explain why I put the storyboards in base styles at the beginning. The thing is that in my original application I have several different arrow pictures, and just didn't want to repeat storyboard definitions. But it seems that I have to.